# R parallel procession: dynamically export and evaluate variables

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I know how to export variables onto clusters registered with `parallel` and `doSNOW`.

What I can't figure out is: how to access these variables (using `clusterEvalQ` or `clusterCall`, for instance) if I don't know their variable names ahead of time.

Take the following contrived example:

```
do_something_parallel <- function(chosen_letter){
  
  a = 1
  b = 2
  c = 3
  
  cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2)
  doSNOW::registerDoSNOW(cl)

  # Export selected letter on clusters
  parallel::clusterExport(cl, chosen_letter, envir = environment())

  # Desired behavior here: multiply selected letter by x2

}

do_something_parallel("a")
do_something_parallel("b")
do_something_parallel("c")
```

The user could select `a`, `b`, or `c` using the `chosen_letter` argument and export it into the clusters. But then how could `chosen_letter` then be accessed if they wanted to, say, multiply it by 2?

I thought of trying to generate expressions using `parse` and `eval` and sending those to `clusterEvalQ` but didn't get anywhere with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very common issue for beginners. The answer is simple: Learn to use lists.

```
do_something_parallel <- function(chosen_letter){
  
  x <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
  y <- x[[chosen_letter]]

  cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2)
  on.exit(parallel::stopCluster(cl))
  doSNOW::registerDoSNOW(cl)
  
  # Export selected letter on clusters
  parallel::clusterExport(cl, "y", envir = environment())
  
  parallel::clusterEvalQ(cl, y * 2)
  
}

do_something_parallel("a")
#[[1]]
#[1] 2
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 2

do_something_parallel("b")
#[[1]]
#[1] 4
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 4

do_something_parallel("c")
#[[1]]
#[1] 6
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 6
```